# xamarin.forms android - service vs TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I need to create a task that runs in the background and does some operation that may take up to a few minutes (and not related to the UI).

I understand that if i create a regular task, the android OS can destroy it after some time, and the solution is to create a background service.

my question is if the line bellow can replace the service, and the task will not be destroyed by android OS until completion of the task:

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyTask(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my question is if the line bellow can replace the service

Yes, you can use long time running task to handle time-consuming operation. Because their essence is the same. IntentService is equivalent of starting a new task at service. You can refer to [the `IntentService` document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).If you do not want to start a task in service please use `Thread` or `Task` and start it at any place you want.

> the task will not be destroyed by android OS until completion of the task

Both IntentService and Task will not be destroyed by android OS until you killed your application.

Comment: in the documentation of xamarin for creating services: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/

Comment: @asaf  Follow the document of google service. You will find there are tow kinds of service the one is `Service` the other one is `IntentService` the `Service` is not a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors). For the time-consuming operation please use `IntentService`. the xamarin guide make service concept fuzzy.

Comment: @Mika so why do i need to use service and not task ? what's the advantage of services over task ? and what the advantegae of TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning over task in android ? my task isn't related to any page / intent. it runs in the background and can run for a few minutes and consume lots of cpu. my concern is that the OS will kill it if low in cpu resources and that the ui will slow dramatically. and i need it to be done also when the app is in background

Comment: @asaf  I mentioned above " their essence is the same. IntentService is equivalent of starting a new task at service" , and they can run at background. But service can be called by system method for example "timer", "Push Notification", and you can create a service out of process and  make service always alive. You can not do that in the task. But in your situation they are same.Both Service and task can do time-consuming operation. OS will kill the application that is not running. And you start a new task or service it will not blocks the UI thread they are different thread. UI will not slow.